# Transparent Tint on Buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

In my Android app, I'm trying to get buttons to be tinted a certain color (either blue, red or gold). The default button tint is grey. Does anyone know how to change the color of the button so that the transparency remains with it?

I tried using:`android:background`

but that ditches the transparency completely and makes the button one solid color.

I also tried using:`android:@color/transparent`

but that ditches the color completely in favor of a fully transparent button. I've looked online for a while and found mostly stuff relating to image buttons. The kind that I'm trying to tint is just the standard Button buttons. I'm also guessing that this can be done mostly just through XML. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could try and create your own button drawable like so...

Take the button drawable from the Android SDK ([ANDROID_SDK_HOME]/platforms/data/res) and import the drawables into your project. Then create a [layer list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) with the button drawable on the bottom and a semi-transparent color on top.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give this a whirl and see how it goes. I appreciate the help.